# Regarding import packages of java

Tags: java

If I import a package and won't use the package, what are the consequences of the java application?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;
```

Above packages are used for my java application,  the third package I never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javap` to check what happens.

Example class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

compile the class and later run `javap -v A` - there is no difference, unused imports don't have impact on the class.